# Form content type for a json HTTP POST?

Tags: json, http, forms

Just wanted a clarification of the form content types:

1. `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`: This is where you can send params encoded with the url.
2. `multipart/form-data`: ??

I need to send a JSON in the post (so it would have the type: `text/x-json`, I guess).
So the question is, is `multipart/form-data` suitable for this purpose / is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` better?

Also, would it be possible to send some params encoded in the url, and some data in the json?

Answer (score 31):

It looks like people answered the first part of your question (use application/json).

For the second part: It is perfectly legal to send query parameters in a HTTP POST Request.

Example:

```
POST /members?id=1234 HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
Content-Type: application/json

{"email":"user@example.com"}
```

Query parameters are commonly used in a POST request to refer to an existing resource. The above example would update the email address of an existing member with the id of 1234.

Comment: The example POST request is perfectly legal, but harder to support than it should be (because people who write HTTP servers expect HTTP POST to always be one of `application/x-www-form-encoded` or `multipart/form-data`, because getting web browsers to use anything else requires some tricky javascript)

Comment: @JeremyList - Web servers don't expect an http post to be one of those two content types. Those content types refer to html forms. The type of data will suggest the content type, eg application/json above.

Comment: @Matt That's what they should do: in practice most servers just treat anything except html form data as null.

Comment: @JeremyList Do you have examples of web servers that treat anything except html form data as null? Every web sever I have used properly handles content-types. Apache httpd and nginx handle this properly. The major scripting languages have built-in web servers that handle this properly.

Comment: @HermanJ.RadtkeIII PHP does not handle content-types properly by default, making it do so requires 4 lines of php for json, plus at least that much for any additional content-type supported. Httpd and nginx do the correct thing when POSTing to cgi and fastcgi scripts (and some other script types but not all), but most scripts don't handle it properly.

Answer (score 6):

I have wondered the same thing. Basically it appears that the html spec has different content types for html and form data. Json only has a single content type.

According to the spec, a POST of json data should have the content-type:
**application/json**

Relevant portion of the [HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/)

> 6.7 Content types (MIME types)
>  ... 
> Examples of content types include "text/html", "image/png", "image/gif", "video/mpeg", "text/css", and
>   "audio/basic".
>
> 17.13.4 Form content types 
> ...
>  application/x-www-form-urlencoded   
> This is the default content type. Forms submitted with this content
>   type must be encoded as follows

Relevant portion of the [JSON spec](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt)

> 1. IANA Considerations
>      The MIME media type for JSON text is application/json.

Comment: Is this an answer or a question?

Answer (score 3):

```
multipart/form-data
```

is used when you want to upload files to the server. Please check [this article](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html) for details.

Comment: I read that article, but it did not state that multipart/form-data is only for file uploads. Is that the case in practice, though?

Comment: Yes. The very common usage is to upload file to server even if it was just included in the specification to package content to submit in several section of a multiform document. If you go to the article and find the word "multipart", you will read: `[...] The default value for this attribute is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". The value "multipart/form-data" should be used in combination with the INPUT element, type="file".`

Comment: If all that's being sent is a single json document it's sometimes better just to use `application/json`, it takes a bit of work to get standard clients and servers to use anything other than `multipart/form-data` and `application/x-www-form-encoded` but doing so is still fully within the standards.