# Call a PHP from another PHP (without cURL)

Tags: php, json, curl, fopen

I have a HTML page that has to call a PHP on another domain. The "Same-Origin-Rule" of most browsers prohibits that call. So I want to call a PHP on my domain to call a PHP on the target domain. I want to avoid cURL so I decided to use `fopen` in that pass-through PHP using `$context`:

```
$params = array('http' => array('method'=>'POST',
                                'header'=>'Content-type: application/json',
                                'content'=>json_encode($_POST)));
$ctx = stream_context_create($params);
$fp = fopen('https://other_domain.com/test.php', 'rb', false, $ctx);
$response = stream_get_contents($fp);
echo $response;
```

But the incoming `$_POST` in test.php seems to be empty. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed it this way:

```
$postData = file_get_contents('php://input');
$params = array('http' => array('method'=>'POST',
                                'header'=>'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                                'content'=>$postData));
$ctx = stream_context_create($params);
$url = 'https://other_domain.com/test.php';
$fp = fopen($url, 'rb', false, $ctx);
$response = stream_get_contents($fp);
echo $response;
```

This easily hands trough all incoming POST data and also forwards any responses. Thanks for all your posts!

Answer (score 2):

Try to build params with http_build_query()

```
$postdata = http_build_query(
    array(
        'json' => json_encode($_POST),
    )
);
```

and then

```
$params = array('http' => array('method'=>'POST',
                            'header'=>'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                            'content'=> $postdata));
```

On the other site get it via `$_POST['json']`

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a server that supports `application/json` as a POST content type, your code isn't going to work:  HTTP servers expect POST data to always be one of `application/x-www-form-encoded` or `multipart/form-data`.  You need to rewrite your code to send the POST data in one of the supported types.

Comment: Not sure you have your facts straight there Fred

Comment: @DavidBarker As I said, _unless you have a server that supports `application/json`_ because stock HTTP servers generally only support the two "standard" form data types. See, for example, comments at [Form content type for a json HTTP POST?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249609/form-content-type-for-a-json-http-post)  I am not aware of any HTTP servers that currently support `application/json` as a content type _out of the box_.

Comment: The server is not the problem, what you're saying is true if you're sending from HTML forms. PHP streams are very different.

Comment: @DavidBarker Ah yes - a different problem space.